# Set all SwipeCards in SwipeCardsView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipeview

I have set  [recycler](/questions/tagged/recycler) view in one [fragment](/questions/tagged/fragment) which consist of 20 records.When I click on any one of [cardview](/questions/tagged/cardview) a [swipeard](/questions/tagged/swipeard) is displayed in next Fragment.I am passing some data from cardview to swipecard.I need to set all 20 SwipeCards after moving to SwipeCard Fragment.But only one SwipeCard is displayed.
This is code for setting [swipecard](/questions/tagged/swipecard)

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp_user_status_info, container, false);
        swipeCardsView=(SwipeCardsView)v.findViewById(R.id.swipeCard);
        infoAdapter=new CurrentInfoAdapter(info,getActivity());
        swipeCardsView.retainLastCard(false);
        swipeCardsView.enableSwipe(true);
        person_name=getArguments().getString("name");
        person_people=getArguments().getString("people");
        person_estimate=getArguments().getString("estimate");
        CurrentInfo currentInfo=new CurrentInfo();
        currentInfo.setName(person_name);
        currentInfo.setPeople(person_people);
        currentInfo.setEstimate(person_estimate);
        Log.i("name",person_name);
        Log.i("people",person_people);
        Log.i("estimate",person_estimate);
        info.add(currentInfo);
        swipeCardsView.setAdapter(infoAdapter);
        return v;
```

This is code for RecyclerView Adapter from where I am passing data to SwipeCardView

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           final CurrentEntry current=filterList.get(position);
          // holder.number.setText(current.getNo());
           holder.Name.setText(current.getName());
           holder.People.setText(current.getPeople());
           holder.Estimate.setText(current.getEstimate());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String name=current.getName();
                    String people=current.getPeople();
                    String estimate=current.getEstimate();
                    Bundle args=new Bundle();
                    args.putString("name",name);
                    args.putString("people",people);
                    args.putString("estimate",estimate);
                  //  UserSatusInfo satusInfo=new UserSatusInfo();
                 //   satusInfo.setArguments(args);
                    TempUserStatusInfo info=new TempUserStatusInfo();
                    info.setArguments(args);
                    AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)v.getContext();
                   // activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,satusInfo).addToBackStack("info").commit();
                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,info).addToBackStack("info").commit();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("name",name);
                }
            });
```

How to get all Cards at a same time after clicking any one card from Recycclerview

Comment: you can pass the complete list to `fragment`

Comment: can you tell me how to pass that list

Comment: check the answer below

Comment: What does T in ArrayList refers to

Comment: `T arrayList` is any arrayList  which implements `Serializable` like `public class CustomModel_Halls implements Serializable` so `T -> CustomModel`

Comment: so you model class have to implement `Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass you complete `arraylist`

```
bundle.putSerializable("key", ArrayList<T extends Serializable> list);
```

and then in fragment recieve

```
ArrayList<T extends Serializable> transactionList = (ArrayList<T extends Serializable>)getArguments().getSerializable("key");
```

Hope this helps.